# How to customize the appearance of a Listview rows

Tags: android, listview, vector, shapes

I would like to have a Listview in which the rows:

- have rounded corners;
- are partially colored (the left part of each row);
- contain a shape in their colored area which is filled with another color.

Here is an example from another app:

[image: piano tiles 2]

I currently have two leads but I did not succeed with any of them.

**My first lead (shape)**

I found how to get rounded corners by using a shape and use it as a background for the Listview.

The drawable shape file "rounded_rectangle.xml":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<shape xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners
        android:bottomRightRadius="7dp"
        android:bottomLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topLeftRadius="7dp"
        android:topRightRadius="7dp"/>

</shape>
```

The activity file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:custom="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    // ...
    <ListView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/splitView"
        android:id="@+id/lv_player"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:background="@drawable/rounded_rectangle"/>

    // ...

</FrameLayout>
```

However, I don't know how to use a shape to have a row partially colored or draw an icon. I can fill the shape with a color but then the rows are completely colored.

**My second lead (vector)**

I also found that I can use a vector as a background of my Listview. The advantage is that I can draw whatever I want using paths.

An example of a vector file:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:height="64dp"
    android:width="64dp"
    android:viewportHeight="600"
    android:viewportWidth="600" >

    <path
        android:name="w"
        android:fillColor="#000000"
        android:pathData="m 290,103 l-200,0 c -50,0 -50,-100 0,-100 l200,0 z"
    />
</vector>
```

I can easily create a path for the colored area of my rows and another for the icon. However, now the problem is that I don't know how to scale the size of the vector to the size of the line.

Do you know what would be the best option and how can I obtain the expected result?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a `CardView`, it will help you to get the rounded corners. Inside the `CardView` create a `RelativeLayout` in order to get the rest of the stuff you've mentioned above.

Here is a good tutorial : [Using the CardView | CodePath Android Cliffnotes](https://guides.codepath.com/android/Using-the-CardView)

Answer (score 1):

First of all you need to create your fancy item separately like having xml layout contain the description of the custom item :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="horizontal">

<TextView
    android:id="@+id/optionName"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="10"
    android:fontFamily="sans-serif-medium"
    android:text="@string/option"
    android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium"
    android:textColor="@android:color/white"
    android:textStyle="bold" />

<CheckBox
    android:id="@+id/activated"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_weight="1"
    android:gravity="center" />

</LinearLayout>
```

than create your adapter that will make your list have your layout as an item

```
public class ListOptionsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
    List<OptionsObject> Features = new ArrayList<OptionsObject>();
    LayoutInflater inflater;
    Context context;
    public ListOptionsAdapter(List<OptionsObject> features, Context context) {
        super();
        Features = features;
        inflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        this.context = context;
    }
    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return Features.size();
    }
    @Override
    public OptionsObject getItem(int position) {
        return Features.get(position);
    }
    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }
    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ViewHolder holder;
        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_list_view, parent, false);
            holder = new ViewHolder();
            holder.optionName = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.optionName);
            holder.isActivate = (CheckBox) convertView.findViewById(R.id.activated);
            convertView.setTag(holder);
        } else {
            holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }
        return convertView;
    }
    static class ViewHolder {
        TextView optionName;
        CheckBox isActivate;
    }
}
```

after that as above i specified the name of the layout i will use as item in the method getView() and affect every element to the view holder

> NB : in getView you have to specify the values for the elements that they will be displayed or leave them blank if u dont need

after that simply in my activity class i call my listview and my adapter

```
OptionList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.optionList);
adapter = new ListOptionsAdapter(Features, getApplicationContext(), this);
OptionList.setAdapter(adapter);
```